# how can i sum special values in nested list of tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

I have a list of list of tuples, like

(a, b, c, d) => c is a's values and d is b's value

```
[
[("A","B",0,3),("A","C",0,3),("B","C",0,3)],
[("A","B",0,3),("A","C",0,3),("B","C",1,1)],
[("A","B",0,3),("A","C",0,3),("B","C",3,0)],
[("A","B",0,3),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",0,3)],
[("A","B",0,3),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",1,1)],
[("A","B",0,3),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",3,0)],
[("A","B",0,3),("A","C",3,0),("B","C",0,3)],
[("A","B",0,3),("A","C",3,0),("B","C",1,1)],
[("A","B",0,3),("A","C",3,0),("B","C",3,0)],
[("A","B",1,1),("A","C",0,3),("B","C",0,3)],
[("A","B",1,1),("A","C",0,3),("B","C",1,1)],
[("A","B",1,1),("A","C",0,3),("B","C",3,0)],
[("A","B",1,1),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",0,3)],
[("A","B",1,1),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",1,1)],
[("A","B",1,1),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",3,0)],
[("A","B",1,1),("A","C",3,0),("B","C",0,3)],
[("A","B",1,1),("A","C",3,0),("B","C",1,1)],
[("A","B",1,1),("A","C",3,0),("B","C",3,0)],
[("A","B",3,0),("A","C",0,3),("B","C",0,3)],
[("A","B",3,0),("A","C",0,3),("B","C",1,1)],
[("A","B",3,0),("A","C",0,3),("B","C",3,0)],
[("A","B",3,0),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",0,3)],
[("A","B",3,0),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",1,1)],
[("A","B",3,0),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",3,0)],
[("A","B",3,0),("A","C",3,0),("B","C",0,3)],
[("A","B",3,0),("A","C",3,0),("B","C",1,1)],
[("A","B",3,0),("A","C",3,0),("B","C",3,0)]
]
```

how can i sum each line of A, B and C values

for example:

for [("A","B",3,0),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",3,0)]

must be

A => 4
B => 3
C => 1

or

for [("A","B",3,0),("A","C",3,0),("B","C",3,0)]

must be

A => 6
B => 3
C => 0

Comment: so what's your problem exactly?? Do you have any compiler error?. In general, if you want to reduce a list to some value you use a `fold`

Comment: I am new in Haskell and trying to find a solution. I have no compiler error,  just want to get the sums

Comment: The common approach in Haskell when you want to summarize a list into a value, you use `foldr` or `foldl'`. Thse are equivalent to `reduce` function in other languages. Another option, more suitable for learning, is to explicitly write a recursive function with an accumulator value (which is exactly what `fold` does)

Answer (score 1):

So the type of your result is to be an *associative array*, with `String` as the key type, and `Int` as the value type. Python calls these things “dictionaries”.

```
A => 4 B => 3 C => 1
```

In Haskell, these are `Map` objects provided by the [`Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html) package.

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.10.5: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
 λ> 
 λ> import qualified Data.Map as M
 λ>
 λ> ma = M.insert "XY" (4::Int) M.empty
 λ> 
 λ> :type ma
 ma :: M.Map [Char] Int
 λ> 
 λ> ma
 fromList [("XY",4)]
 λ> 
 λ> mb = M.insert  "AB" 5  ma
 λ> 
 λ> mb
 fromList [("AB",5),("XY",4)]
 λ> 
 λ> mc = M.insert "AB" 12 mb
 λ> 
 λ> mc
 fromList [("AB",12),("XY",4)]
 λ>
```

Now what if we want a new colliding value to be *combined* with the existing one, instead of just replacing it as shown above ? In that case, we need the [`insertWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html#v:insertWith) library function.

```
 λ> 
 λ> mc = M.insertWith (+) "AB" 100 mb
 λ> 
 λ> mc
 fromList [("AB",105),("XY",4)]
 λ>
```

Back to our initial problem: we are starting from say `[("A","B",3,0),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",3,0)]`. The first thing is to transform this input into a proper list of `(String, Int)` pairs:

```
 λ> 
 λ> tsa = [("A","B",3,0),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",3,0)]
 λ> 
 λ> flatten ts = concatMap  (\(a,b,c,d) -> [(a,c),(b,d)])  ts
 λ> 
 λ> flatten tsa
 [("A",3),("B",0),("A",1),("C",1),("B",3),("C",0)]
 λ>
```

The next step is to *fold* this pair list into the `Map` object we want, using `insertWith` as the step function of the fold. We need to import a folding function:

```
 λ> 
 λ> import qualified Data.List as L
 λ> 
 λ> :type L.foldl'
 L.foldl' :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
 λ>
```

where `t a` is to be `[(String,Int)]` and `b` is to be our `Map` type.

Next, we define our step function:

```
 λ> 
 λ> stepFn map (k,v) = M.insertWith (+) k v map
 λ> 
 λ> :type  L.foldl' stepFn (M.empty :: M.Map String Int)
 L.foldl' stepFn (M.empty :: M.Map String Int)
     :: Foldable t => t (String, Int) -> M.Map String Int
 λ>
```

This last expression has exactly the type we need. Let's try it:

```
 λ> 
 λ> for2 = L.foldl' stepFn (M.empty :: M.Map String Int)
 λ> 
 λ> for ts = for2 (flatten ts)
 λ> 
 λ> tsa
 [("A","B",3,0),("A","C",1,1),("B","C",3,0)]
 λ> 
 λ> for tsa
 fromList [("A",4),("B",3),("C",1)]
 λ>
```

This is the expected result.

Let's summarize our code:

```
import qualified  Data.List  as  L
import qualified  Data.Map   as  M

flatten :: [(String, String, Int, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
flatten t4s = concatMap  (\(a,b,c,d) -> [(a,c),(b,d)])  t4s

stepFn :: M.Map String Int -> (String, Int) -> M.Map String Int
stepFn ma (k,v) = M.insertWith (+) k v ma

for :: [(String, String, Int, Int)] -> M.Map String Int
for t4s = L.foldl' stepFn M.empty (flatten t4s)
```

This last one can also be written as a composition:

```
for = (L.foldl' stepFn M.empty)  .  flatten
```

I would also suggest to pick a different name for this function. As in many programming languages, `for` is already taken in Haskell.